# Does anyone know how to change the character of a textfield caret with javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, textfield, caret

Like the title reads, I want to change the character of a caret. Maybe make it a letter or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something near this, but its very dificult.

1. In you textfield bind a event to keydown, for example.
2. Each char typed, you slide a floating `<img>` above textarea.
3. If user click in textarea, update position getting X and Y from onclick.

Obs: the font must be monospaced. Ex: if every font have 20px and user press backspace, you slide this gif to the left 20px.

---

**EDIT**

I just made a hello world, in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwTPs/3/).

Of course, it's an example, but test typing and use backspace and enter to see caret go back and foward.

In this example there are a lot of bugs to fix, like:

- Use of `<backspace>` that cleans all line
- Use of arrows that in overflow textarea margins
- Use of mouse must update caret position...

Comment: There are many other cases to consider that make this difficult; e.g. selection of text, moving about using hotkeys, zoom, etc. FWIW, I couldn't get the jsfiddle demo to work at all in IE.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: I've actually just recently found an example here: http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html but I can't seem to extract the necessary elements and integrate it into my code... but thanks anyway.

Comment: @scuba - That's not replacing the caret, it's hiding it and showing something another block element :)

Comment: OK, do you know of a simpler way to do that? Or a way to explain it to a JS newb like myself? I can't make sense of this demo...

Comment: You'll note that the demo page doesn't work properly with text selection, zoom, etc.